# Returning a generic typed object from a method. Getting Class<SomeType> instead of SomeType

Tags: java, generics

I am writing a method to deserialize a json response as follows:

```
public <T> T parse(T t) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = getMapper(contentType);
    T o = (T) mapper.readValue(getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream(), t.getClass());
    return o;
}
```

My expectation was to use the above method as:

```
SomeType object = parse(SomeType.class);
```

However, the IDE is telling me that `parse` method returns a `Class<SomeType>`. How an I fix it? I looked at the implementation of ObjectMapper.readValue (in Jackson library), but I don't think I need that complexity.

Comment: I want to bring your attention to `T t` and `T o` variable declarations.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis , good point. I should have noticed that if t (small) is an object of Class type, then o will be similar. Some other language, may allow me to use 't o' where I have 'T o' right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work I guess

```
public <T> T parse(Class<T> classType) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = getMapper(contentType);       
        T o = mapper.readValue(getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream(), classType);
        return o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this method signature:

```
public <T> T parse(T t)...
```

to

```
public <T> T parse(Class<T> t)...
```

If you want a class to be supplied.

Comment: They'll have to change the `t.getClass()` as well.